# Using an insert id from first of three queries in php

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update, lastinsertid

I want to store the data from several curl calls to an initial table, but last insert id is inserting wrong info

Query 1 inserts data into table

table1

```
   id name      email      valuereturn
   1   val     val@email.com       0
```

I then post data 3 times to my system and log it

table2

```
    id  name    system  valuereturn
    1   val      5       0
    2   val      0       0
    3   val      0       0
```

the max value returned from my system i want to update table 1

```
update table1 
set valuereturn = '5' 
where id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

does not work because last insert id is 3 from table2, how can I use something like `last_insert_id(Table1)`?

i want to update my

Comment: Well, you can't. You have to retrieve and remember it in a PHP variable.

Comment: @AndreKR can you reply with that as the answer because that is what i did. idk why i didnt think of it, its one class so i just called a  mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()") after my insert and saved it to global variable!! ty

Comment: I did, but apparently I was only half right, it doesn't have to be a *PHP* variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't. You have to retrieve and remember it in a PHP variable.

Or go for Saharsh's solution and remember it in a *MySQL* variable.

Answer (score 1):

Store that **LAST_INSERT_ID()** of table1 in a variable and than use that variable in update query.

```
INSERT INTO table1(name) values ('Saharsh');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @table1Id;

INSERT INTO table2(name, table1id) values ('Saharsh', @table1Id);
UPDATE table1 SET valuereturn = '5' WHERE id = @table1Id;
```

Comment: will this work on one mysql connection?

or will it merge if i have parrallell inserts to both tables?

Comment: It will work for one mysql session. You can also create procedure to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

#### In PHP I assume you use the following code:

```
<?php
  connect_db();
  insert_first_query_to_table1();
  insert_second_query_to_table2();
  update_query_setting(last_insert_id());
?>
```

#### If that's the case, I suggest you to use a temp variable to store the `last_insert_id`.

```
<?php
  connect_db();
  insert_first_query_to_table1();
  $setVal = last_insert_id();
  insert_second_query_to_table2();
  update_query_setting($setVal);
?>
```

Hope this helps.

*PS: This is a pseudo code!*

Comment: this is what i did, but it was more oop than that